# multable cloth animation

Tags: animation

I have different cloths but in the animation they are getting inside themselves.
I want to see red, yellow and purple on blue in every frame. I have tried colliding options but it didnt work. Which options should i change?

Best.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if this is intended to be some kind of quilt pattern, you could consider only having one cloth simulation and using texturing (instead of multiple cloth simulations) to create the look of multiple types attached together. My view is that simulations should be avoided whenever possible, and to the greatest extent possible, because they are often slow, and sometimes buggy.

Comment: please check these pictures,

https://hizliresim.com/9PgfcI

https://hizliresim.com/gX3b9W

what should i do to get result like first picture even if i put 10 different cloth material?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you need to enable the self collisions for each one.

You can see where it is:

[image]

Comment: i have tried that but it didnt work let me try it one more time.

''denedim ama olmadı ya, bakayim bir daha.''

Comment: "Bazen aşağıdaki zaman çizelgesinde ilerleyip durdurduğunda istemediğin görüntüler olabiliyor anlamsız bir şekilde. Bu bozulmalara örnek olarak önceden takip ettiğim bir kişinin bir videosundaki durumu verebilirim linki ve saniyeyi aşağı koyucam. Ayrıca nasıl bir animasyonun var eğer objeleri döndürüyorsan birbirlerine geçmiş olabilirler. "  Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogWQs_7DU0Y Dakika ve saniye : 16.48

Comment: well if you add one collision to top cloth material it works perfectly fine.
i mean ball has collision
first cloth have cloth + collision
second cloth have just cloth.
that works perfectly fine.
when you add third cloth and add collision to second cloth it brakes again.

i prepare some pictures

https://hizliresim.com/9PgfcI

https://hizliresim.com/gX3b9W

Comment: hocam blender'da hemen bir top yapıp collision ver üzerine subsurface'li 2 tane plane koy aralıklı ilk plane'e cloth+collision ikincisine(üsttekine) sadece cloth ver. bir sorun olmuyor. 3. planei koymaya çalışıp ikincisine collision verdiğinde mevzu patlıyor.

sorry for different language, i can translate if you want.

Comment: Blender ile çok ileri bir tecrübem yok, arkadaşımla yaptığımız oyunlara model tasarlıyorum bazen de youtube da gördüğüm eğitimlerden bir şeyler öğreniyorum. Öyle olunca  bu konuda çok da bi fikre sahip değilim. Bir ara oyun için korsan gemisi lazım olmuştu ben de orada bir bayrak yapmıştım o kadar. Kusura bakma yardımcı olamadım.

Comment: grabcad gibi sitelerden bedava çizimler var onlaralardan model bulabilirsin ama uzantılara dikkat et başka bir yazılım ile .stl formatına çevirmen gerekebilir. oradan aldığın modelleri low-poly yapabilirsin. veya direk blender'da low-poly çalışabilirsin. youtube'a low-poly blender yazarsan çıkıyor baya birşey. kolay gelsin.

Comment: Sağol teşekkür ederim. Oyunumuzda ilerde Steam gibi platformlarda paylaşmak ve özgün olmasını istediğimiz için tamamen kendimiz yapıyoruz.

Comment: Indie tarzi birsey yapin mobile ve pc icin. Biraz para gecsin elinize. Simdi low poly akimi var onu yakalayin. Yapmasi kolay en azindan.

Comment: Aynen low poly yapıyoruz oyunumuzu. Geçmişte yaptığımız 3 acemi oyunumuz var Google Play'de ama oradan sonra geliştirdik kendimizi.

Comment: ben şunu baya oynadım mesela,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YGTxqPazlA
biraz daha özellik eklenmesi lazım
belki şu tarz animasyonlar vs de olur 
https://www.instagram.com/p/B_f0w87nZmR/